# How to execute partial views in RazorEngine

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, razorengine, razorgenerator

I have an MVC web API project that includes a folder views/forms, and i want to read the view as HTML string including the partial views;

this is my code to get the HTML string from the view

```
 public class HtmlActionResult : IHttpActionResult
    {
        private const string ViewDirectory = @"..\Views\Forms";
        private readonly string _view;
        private readonly dynamic _model;


        public HtmlActionResult(string viewName, dynamic model)
        {
            _view = LoadView(viewName);
            _model = model;
        }

        public Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            var parsedView = RazorEngine.Razor.Parse(_view, _model);
            response.Content = new StringContent(parsedView);
            response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html");
            return Task.FromResult(response);
        }

        private static string LoadView(string name)
        {
            string path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/views/forms");

            path = Path.Combine(path, name + ".cshtml");

            string view = string.Empty;

            if (File.Exists(path))
                view = File.ReadAllText(path);

            return view;
        }
```

Here's how its Executed :

```
var htmlAction = new HtmlActionResult("MyView", MyModel);
var response = await htmlAction.ExecuteAsync(new CancellationToken());
```

MyView contains a partial view in the same folder (views/forms) called `separator.cshtml`

How can i render the partial view `separator.cshtml`, i tried adding a reference resolver like stated here:

[Reference resolver for Rezor Engine](https://antaris.github.io/RazorEngine/ReferenceResolver.html)

and added the following code before getting the HTML response string:

```
var config = new TemplateServiceConfiguration();
config.ReferenceResolver = new MyIReferenceResolver();
var service = RazorEngineService.Create(config);
```